# Is it possible to make a C++ function that accepts multiple data types?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a Matrix class that must support multiple operations. One of them is to multiply a matrix by either another matrix, or a scalar of the same type of the matrix data. Another is to implement the *= operator.

Current code (working):

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*=(const Matrix<T> &rhs) {
    Matrix<T> lhs = *this;
    *this = lhs*rhs;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*=(T num) {
    Matrix<T> lhs = *this;
    *this = lhs * num;
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(T scalar) const {
    Matrix<T> result(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            //std::cout << "adding elements at [" << i << "][" << j << "]" << std::endl;
            result[i][j] = this->data[i][j] * scalar;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const Matrix<T> &b) const {
    Matrix<T> a = *this;
    if(a.cols != b.rows)
        throw DimensionMismatchException();
    int rows = a.rows;
    int cols = b.cols;
    Matrix<T> result(rows, cols);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++)
            result[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
    return result;
}
```

My question: is it possible to implement the *= operator such that there does not need to be 2 different functions? I am also curious if something similar can be done with the * operator as well, given that the code in those methods is very different due to the nature of matrix multiplication so things are a little more elegant.

Comment: What you ask for is not practical and any attempt to merge into one function will end up more complicated than necessary. This is good as it is!

Comment: Thlooks like the right approach without talking about style. If you want more opinions you should post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Since the two `operator*` functions are quite different, how do you propose unify them?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf By taking a generic template parameter, strengthen the function by some complicated SFINAE, then use `constexpr if` in the body to separate. Yeah, it's not worth it...

Comment: @DeiDei [Sometimes it is.](http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-06-10)

Answer (score 3):

Functions should do one thing and do it well. If you find that you have two very different implementations in the same function, chances are your code would be more maintainable and easier to read if you split the function.

The split you have here is a good one. It is immediately clear that operator* has two main cases to contend with. One where you multiply by a scalar and another where you multiply by a matrix.